# Can't import "Pacifico" font in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts

I cannot use the [Pacifico](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Pacifico) font on React Native. Although I think I have followed all the necessary steps, it cannot recognise the font.

The project when compiled gives no error.

I downloaded the `.ttf` file and added it in a `fonts` folder located in `assets`.

I ran the command `npx react-native-asset` and built the project again.

File `react-native.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
};
```

Interested file:

```js
<Text style={styles.title}>Test</Text>

title: {
    fontFamily: "Pacifico-Regular", 
    fontSize: 50,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
```

**P.S** I'm not using a library, I imported everything manually, as there is no direct compatibility between Google Fonts and React-Native.